# Combining sf files with different geometry types and then finding which ones are within certain distance of each other in r

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have updated this question. I have figured out a work around to my original problem of combining points, lines and polygons into the same sf file. I simply turned all my points and lines into polygons (see code below). However, now I still can't get the buffer to work properly so the problem still persists:

I have a dataset containing populations of different species in and around Chicago, USA. Some of the populations are large and thus denoted by several points (several lat/long coordinates = polygons). Others are small and thus simply represented by a single point (1 lat/long coordinate). Finally, some are long and narrow and thus denoted by two points (2 lat/long coordinates). Note that a population may be associated with multiple species (though my example dataset here only includes one species with different populations).

I want to analyze the populations for each species but before I can I need to make sure they match my definition of SEPARATE populations. I define a population as being separate if it is at least 50 meters from any other population of the same species. Thus, I want to write a script that goes through my dataset, groups populations by species and then determines if any population (points, lines and polygons) is within 50 meters of any other population for a given species. Here is my abbreviated dataset (the full dataset has about 300 species and 600K lines of data).

```
      data <- data.frame (species = c("species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2", "species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2","species_2"),
                pop_id = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2),
                coordinate_type = c("decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees","decimal degrees"),
                coordinate_system = c("WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84","WGS84"),
                sptaial_object_type = c("Point","Point","Point","Polygon","Polygon","Polygon","Polygon","Polygon","LineString","LineString","Polygon","Polygon","Polygon","Polygon","Polygon","Point"),
                POINT_X = c(-87.64021, -88.13841, -87.64021, -88.13898, -88.13902, -88.13900, -88.13895, -88.13898, -88.18663, -88.18659, -88.13994, -88.14022, -88.14000, -88.13978, -88.13994, -87.64021),
                POINT_Y = c(41.07428, 41.34244, 41.07428, 41.33813, 41.33821, 41.33824, 41.33820, 41.33813, 41.36329, 41.36348, 41.33817, 41.33833, 41.33858, 41.33817, 41.33817, 41.07428))
```

Here is what I have successfully done:

```
    ######################
    ##                  ##
    ## LOAD PACKAGES    ##
    ##                  ##
    ######################
    
    # Load required packages
    library(data.table)
    library(geosphere)
    library(sp)
    library(rgdal)
    library(sf)
    library(dplyr)   


    ##################################
    ##   TURN POINTS INTO POLYGONS  ##
    ##################################

    #Duplicate all rows that contain points to get 4 new dataframes with only the points
    data_points_1 <- subset(data_1, data_1$sptaial_object_type=="Point") #Save only the rows that are points
    data_points_2 <- subset(data_1, data_1$sptaial_object_type=="Point") #Save only the rows that are points
    data_points_3 <- subset(data_1, data_1$sptaial_object_type=="Point") #Save only the rows that are points
    data_points_4 <- subset(data_1, data_1$sptaial_object_type=="Point") #Save only the rows that are points

    #Increase all POINT_Y in data_points_2 and all POINT_X in data_points_3 by 0.001
    data_points_2$POINT_Y <- data_points_2$POINT_Y + 0.001
    data_points_3$POINT_X <- data_points_2$POINT_X + 0.001

    #Rbind the points dataframes back together and change Point attribute to Polygon
    data_points_final <- rbind(data_points_1, data_points_2, data_points_3, data_points_4)
    data_points_final$sptaial_object_type <- "Polygon"
    head(data_points_final) #Now every point has been turned into a polygon with 2 slightly offset, 
    #new points and two original points (starting and ending vertices of the polgyon)

    #################################
    ##   TURN LINES INTO POLYGONS  ##
    #################################

    #For every subpop that has a line add one more point by taking any of the existing points and adding to the x AND the y coordinate
    data_linestring_1 <- subset(data_1, data_1$sptaial_object_type=="LineString") #Save only the rows that are linestrings
    data_linestring_2 <- data_linestring_1 %>%  distinct(species, pop_id, .keep_all = T)  #Save only rows with unique combos of species and pop_id 
    data_linestring_3 <- data_linestring_1 %>%  distinct(species, pop_id, .keep_all = T)  #Save only rows with unique combos of species and pop_id 

    #Increase all POINT_Y and all POINT_X in data_linestring_2 by  0.001
    data_linestring_2$POINT_Y <- data_linestring_2$POINT_Y + 0.001
    data_linestring_2$POINT_X <- data_linestring_2$POINT_X + 0.001

    #Rbind the points dataframes back together and change Point attribute to Polygon
    data_linestring_final <- rbind(data_linestring_1, data_linestring_2, data_linestring_3)
    data_linestring_final$sptaial_object_type <- "Polygon"

    #Check that each linestring has now been turned into a polygon with 3 points
    head(data_linestring_final) #Now every line has been turned into 
    #a polygon with 2 slightly offset, new points and two original points (starting and ending vertices of the polygon)

    #################################################################################        ############
    ##       RECOMBINE POINTS LINES AND POLYGONS INTO ONE DATAFRAME                                    ##
    #################################################################################        ############

    #extract only the polygons from the original dataframe 
    data_polygons_final <- subset(data_1, data_1$sptaial_object_type=="Polygon") #Save only the rows that are points

    #Combine polygons, lines and points
    data_all_polygons <- rbind(data_points_final, data_linestring_final, data_polygons_final )



    ################THIS PART NEEDS TO BE TURNED INTO A FOR LOOP LATER FOR ALL SPECIES################
    unique_species <- unique(data_all_polygons$species)
    #for (i in 1:length(unique_species)) {   
    i=1 #assign 1 to i since for loop isn't working yet

    data_all_polygons_2 <- data_all_polygons[data_all_polygons$species %in% unique_species[i],] #pull out columns for species i

    #Now convert dataframe to spatial object and assign coordinate system (3528 = Illinois East from https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3528/)
    data_all_polygons_3 <- st_as_sf(data_all_polygons_2, coords = c("POINT_X", "POINT_Y"), crs = 3528)


    #Turn all coordinates into spatial polygons (from  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332427/converting-points-to-polygons-by-group)
    data_all_polygons_4 = st_sf( aggregate( data_all_polygons_3$geometry, list(data_all_polygons_3$species_full.subpop_id), function(g){st_cast(st_combine(g),"POLYGON")} )) 


    #Create 50 meter buffer around all subpopulations and get overlaps between subpops
    data_all_polygons_50m_buffer <- st_buffer(data_all_polygons_4, 50)#Create 50 meter buffer around all subpopulations

    intersection_output <-as.data.frame(st_intersection(x=data_all_polygons_50m_buffer,y=data_all_polygons_50m_buffer) %>% #Get any intersections between all subpopulations mutate(n_overlaps = lengths(st_within(geometry, data_all_polygons_50m_buffer)))) #add intersections to new column in dataframe 

    #Clean output table to leave only unique overlaps
    intersection_output_final <- as.data.frame(intersection_output %>% dplyr::filter(n_overlaps >'0') %>% #remove any columns that show zero overlaps
    filter(Group.1 != Group.1.1) %>% #remove any columns that show 1 overlap as this is the overlap of one subpop with itself
    group_by(grp = paste(pmax(Group.1, Group.1.1), pmin(Group.1, Group.1.1), sep = "_")) %>% slice(1) %>%  ungroup() %>%  select(-grp)) #remove any reversed duplicate rows (mirror duplicates)
```

This all runs smoothly but there is something going wrong in the buffer - the output table gives me many intersections between the buffers but plugging the coordinates of the subpopulations (that are within 50meters according to my output) into Google maps shows that most intersections are between populations that are many miles apart. So my buffer is not working right because I only want intersections between pops that are 50m or less apart. I assume this has something to do with projection but after searching for weeks online I can't find out what it is. I assigned my dataset to crs = 3528 as that is what I found online. I've also tried many others including just using WGS84. The only thing I know from my data is that it is associated with WGS84 and that the coordinates are lat/long from the Chicago area.

Comment: You probably have to buffer first before joining. Once you buffer, all of the data will be in polygons, which will be easier to join.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @at80. That would probably also work. I have already pursued a different workaround which was to just turn the points and lines into polygons (very similar to your suggestion) but I like yours better so I'd like to use that in the final script. In any case, I can't get the buffer/intersect to work. It is not throwing any errors but the output includes intersections between populations that are much more than 50 m apart. I assume I'm doing something wrong with the projection but I can't figure out what.